# OneToOne Mapping does not set mapped object

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, cascade, one-to-one

I have 3 classes namely `Satislar`, `Urunler` and `Musteriler`

In Satislar class, there is 2 foreign keys: `urunid` and `musteriid`

Every `Satislar` object has one `Urunler` object and one `Musteriler` object.

So I need two different OneToOne mapping in my `Satislar` class. First to `Urunler` and second to `Musteriler`.

When I add a new Satislar object to database, I will use existing `Musteriler` object and `Urunler` object. Code must not create new `Musteriler`, `Urunler` objects.
To achieve that I have used

```
(insertable= false, updatable=false)
```

But I can not set `Urunler` and `Musteriler` objects to a `Satislar` object. It says :

> column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

I think I have a problem with annotations.

Here is my code blocks.

```
...
Session session = null;    
Urunler urun = gelenUrunler.get(tblUrunler.getSelectedRow());
Musteriler musteri = gelenMusteriler.get(cmbMusteriler.getSelectedIndex());
System.out.println(musteri.getId() + "asd " + urun.getId());
Satislar satis = new Satislar();
satis.setUrun(urun);
satis.setMusteri(musteri);
satis.setAdet(Integer.valueOf(txtAdet.getText().trim()));
satis.setTarih(new Date());

try {

    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    session.save(satis);    
    session.getTransaction().commit();  

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Satış sırasında hata oluştu." + e);
} finally {
    session.close();        
}
...
```

Satislar class:

```
...
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "urunid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Integer urunid;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "adet")
private Integer adet;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "musteriid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Integer musteriid;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "tarih")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date tarih;




@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "urunid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Urunler urun;

public Urunler getUrun() {
    return urun;
}

public void setUrun(Urunler urun) {
    this.urun = urun;
}

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "musteriid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Musteriler musteri;

public Musteriler getMusteri() {
    return musteri;
}

public void setMusteri(Musteriler musteri) {
    this.musteri = musteri;
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made everything non-insertable and non-updatable. So Hibernate doesn't insert anything in the columns when it inserts the Satislar.

Remove the `urunid` and `musteriid` fields: they're useless. You already have a OneToOne association, which is sufficient.

Then remove the `insertable` and `updatable` attributes from the two `JoinColumn` annotations.

Also, if several Satislar refer to the same Urunler or Musteriler, what you actually have is a ManyToOne association, and not a OneToOne.

And finally, `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` is very dubious: if an Urunler can exist without a Satislar, then you probably don't want to create/remove an Urunler when creating/removing a Satislar.

Comment: I made simple mistakes because of this is my first project with Hibernate. Your answer solved it .Thanks . The reason why urunid and musteriid is there I totally forgot to delete them. And I was thinking insertable and updatable is used to prevent the other table to change. I think cascade options do that. I have changed OneToOne to ManyTo One . This was my biggest mistake.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify the `@JoinColumn(name = "column_id")` for the relation, hibernate will figure out `column_id` as the foreignkey column for the relation. You just have to add the entities together and save them.

```
Satislar s = new Satislar();

Urunler u = new Urunler();

Musteriler m = new Musteriler();

s.setUrun(u);
s.setMusteri(m);

session.save(s);
```

You should remove the  `urunid` and `musteriid` fields from `Satislar` and specify the column names as you want for those columns in the `JoinColumn` annotation.

```
@Entity
public class Satislar {
   ....

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "urun_id")
    private Urunler urun;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "musteri_id")
    private Musteriler musteri;
    ....
}
```

Hope this helps.